# GPS is always indicated as on

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, gps, samsung

I just recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Star S5280 which runs on Android OS, v4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) and it keeps indicating that my GPS is on. I already deactivated my mobile network on both SIM cards. I have also deactivated my location services. Can anybody tell me what to do about this because it drains my battery without me even using it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Data doesn't have anything to do with the GPS. Go to your settings, then go to Location Access under `Personal`, and then turn both "WiFi & mobile network location" and "GPS Satellites" off. That should turn your GPS on the phone completely off.

You can also look in your settings to see if you can set up a toggle to quickly turn the GPS, as well as many other services on or off just by swiping down from the top notification bar.